# How do I call a Rails helper method from inside another helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I am writing a helper that needs to call another helper, which generates html. How do I do that?

Answer (score 19):

try: 
include AnotherHelper

Answer (score 5):

Just call it.

If it is in a different helper file, your controller can include the other helpfile by using the controller method "[helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#M000292)"

Added:

Here is an example:

```
# in the view
<%= my_helper %>

# in the helper file
def my_helper
  "<div>" + someother_helper_which_generates_html + "</div>"
end
```

** Please add more details to your question if this isn't helping....

Comment: This answer does not address the question. It asks how to use one **Helper** from within another **Helper**, instead you are demonstrating usage of **Helper** in a **View**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you (say, in application_helper.rb)

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def create_div
    html("this is some content")
  end

  def html(content)
    "<div>#{content}</div>"
  end

end
```

In this case, the create_div method is calling the html method with a string as an argument.  the html method returns a string of HTML with the argument you supply embedded. in a view, it would look like:

```
<%= create_div %>
```

hope this helps!